# Unable to run multiple instance of Xulrunner

Tags: firefox, xul, xulrunner

I have a simple hello world application in xulrunner. I need to be able to run multiple instance of the application. However when I run the application from commandline if one is already running, i get[image: error message]

I've tried several methods like

1. setting MOZ_NO_REMOTE=1

`xulrunner application.ini --port=45333`

2. setting -no-remote

`xulrunner -no-remote application.ini` (doesn't work, coz xulrunner doesn't take -no-remote parameter)

I'm using xulrunner runtime 20.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working. The idea is to run two instances with two different profiles
 with `-profile /tempdir/` option.